# How to use TMS3705 RFid transponder base station IC

Tags: c, embedded, rfid

I'm looking for sample code on how to use the TMS3705 RFid transponder base station IC to communicate with the TMS37157 RFid device. 
The TMS3705 datasheet is not very helpful - it only describes the physical interface.
Either sample code or a good description of how to construct/send a transmit packet and receive/parse a receive packet would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TMS3705 is used in the **PaLFI Evaluation kit TMS37157**. You find the reference to the 
[FAQ](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ml/swra309a/swra309a.pdf).